# Sort a textrange with links restored using Slides Service of Google Apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides-api, google-slides

I have slide file where I need to sort the shape text with hyperlink
The below code removes the hyperlinks in shapetext
I need to sort the text with **hyperlinks and formatting** not being removed.

```
function myFunction() {
  var ppt = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation().getSlides()[0].getPageElements()[0].asShape().getText().asString().split("\n").sort()
}
```

**UPDATE:**
**INPUT**
[HERE is the sample slide file](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/16orElHeQ-lkitXekJwxg35Ru4bVgOX1VUhoYIhOw12I/copy)

**EXPECTED OUTPUT (after sorting text)**
[image]

[image]

Comment: I would like to confirm your sample situation. In your sample image, it seems that each text line is splitted by `\n`, and the hyperlink is set all text in a line, and the blank line is not existing. Is my understanding correct? For the sample situation, if you have other patterns, please show us.

Comment: Hi Tanaike, I updated my question and I have also attached a link of the slide file. Thanks so mych for your help.

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding more information. Is your sample image is the output image or the input image? If it's the output image, can I ask you about the input image you expect? If it's the input image, can I ask you about the output image? By the way, if you have other patterns, please show us. And, in your situation, Slides API is used? I thought that when more information is included, it will help users think of the solution. I apologize for this.

Comment: Thanks Tanaike, I updated to show expected output and input text.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. I have one more question. In your situation, Slides API is used?

Comment: Your English is perfectly understandible. Not used API, only Slides Service used.

Comment: Doing Apps Script one think that you can do is retrieve the [links](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/text-range#getlinks) and put it back on after sorting. But this could be difficult depending on the data that you have. You would need to keep track of where the linked line has ended. In the end problem with your code is that [`asString()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/text-range#asstring) just removes all the [TextStyle](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/text-style). Are the links different words every time?

Comment: Yes thats my thought @Tanaike Do you have any suggestions or can you show me how its possible using the API?

Comment: Thank you for replying. In this case, I thought that the script became a bit complecate. So when I found the simpler logic for achieving your goal, I would like to propose it. I deeply apologize that I cannot resolve your issue soon. This is due to my poor skill.

Comment: I appreciate your time and help. If possible via API too, you are also welcome. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I've tried an approach that could work in some cases. But before posting, would the words to be linked repeat in your text? For example would you use the word **link** multiple times each time with a different link (or one time with link and the other without)?

Comment: yes in call cases it may repeat.

Comment: Sorry for the long post and all the question but as you are seeing there is no easy way to make this work. How are you creating all the text boxes? maybe you could sort it before it is even inserted.If not maybe instead of sorting create another new whole textbox, but that still needs to know all the links and their placement without resorting to converting the box to a string (therefore losing all the style).

Comment: So what j understand is there is no solution

Comment: No there seems to be no easy solution for this case in particular. I've tried. But from this point you would need to get every word and index, keep track of all the styles and index and then create a new text box. Maybe manipulating the text order withoult altering styles could be a very good feature to ask in [Google Issue Tracker](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker).

Comment: Yes ok let's not bother about it.